# HTML 5 + CSS3 navbar not looking like how I want it

Tags: html, css, web, navbar

So I'm having issues with my navbar and I don't know how to fix it. I looked around already, but none seems to work.

Okay, so what I want is to push the menu items to the right and the logo to the left. I can't seem to get that working.

(SOLVED) Lastly, (this is more if my first problems get resolved), does anyone know what it's called when you resize the page and everything in the site resizes properly to fit the screen size? I'm trying to get that on my website. (SOLVED)

Thanks guys! And sorry if this is a very noobish question, I've been doing web design for a bit, but never really ventured this far into it. So take it easy on me. :)

LINK: http://jsfiddle.net/u659zbgk/1/

```css
@charset"utf-8";

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/*Navigation Start*/

#navbar {
  height: 50px;
  background: #752C8D;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

#logo {
  background: #752C8D;
  padding-left: 35px;
  float: left;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #752C8D;
}

nav ul {} nav ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Gotham;
}

a {
  text-shadow: #000;
  float: left;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: lighter;
  padding-bottom: 12.5px;
  padding-top: 12.5px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  background-color: #752C8D;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #FFF;
  float: left;
  background: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 12.5px;
  padding-top: 12.5px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-left: 12px;
}

a:target {
  color: #F90;
  background: #000
}
/*End Navigation*/

@font-face {
  font-family: Gotham;
  src: url('font/gothambold1.ttf');
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <section id="navbar">
    <header id="logo">
      <img src="images/header/sidenavbar_01.png" width="111" height="47" alt="RobotEx">
    </header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">BEST</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Company</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Team</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Product</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Community</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Photos</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>
  <!---Content for  class "wrapper" Goes Here--->
</div>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <section id="navbar">
      <header id="logo">RobotEx</header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">BEST</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Company</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Team</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Product</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Community</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Photos</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </section>
    <!---Content for  class "wrapper" Goes Here--->
  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be very useful if you can post your code in yor question, and a code snippet or link to a **minimal example of your issue**. We discourage users from linking to external sites due to risk of link rot. You also have too many questions in a single question — it helps to have a **specific question/issue**.

Comment: In addition to what @Terry mentioned, you may be attempting to fix the problem as we work on it and becomes a moving target. Questions are meant to be helpful for future users of this site which won't be the case if you fix your problem. Pease also read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Further more by breaking down the problem to a small example of the problem, the solution my present itself.

Comment: Lastly the term you are looking for is Resposnive Design, sometimes called Fluid Design.

Comment: Thanks. I will rewrite the original problem to pose a specific issue and I will post a jsfiddle link so the issue is better resolved. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: Not just a fliddle link please, Code in the body of the question in prefered. Use the `{}` button. Or better still discover the "Snippet" button <kbd>Ctrl + M</kbd>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fix for the menu:**

```
#navbar {
    height: 55px;
    background: #752C8D;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

nav {
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 78%;
    background: #752C8D;
}
nav ul {margin-top: 0;}
```

Insert this on your header or somewhere in your html file. What this does is to add a class named "current" to any link that is the same as the current address

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
      $(this).addClass('current');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

CSS

```
a.current {
    background:black;
    color:white;
}
```

**You can also accomplish it with this other method only with HTML by adding a class to the links:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="home" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="best" href="best.html">BEST</a></li>
    <li><a class="company" href="company.html">Company</a></li>
    <li><a class="team" href="team.html">Team</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.home a.home,
.best a.best,
.company a.company,
.team a.team {
    background:black;
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your html a little bit do it does what you mentioned in your first point. Notice how I added a div that you didn't have before and some style.

```
.divFloatL {
    float: left;
}

<section id="navbar">
   <div id="logo" class="divFloatL">
      <img src="images/header/sidenavbar_01.png" width="111" height="47" alt="RobotEx">
   </div>
   <div class="divFloatL">
      <nav>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">BEST</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
   </div>
</section>
```

Regarding the Responsive Design you are looking for, there are several ways to achieve that, the one I am most familiar with is Twitter Bootstrap. I recommend you to take a look at it. They also have a component included that highlights the tab that you have selected.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav

If you study that, it will take care of your other 2 questions.